# Bad configuration in Logstash - Windows 11

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I try execute input jdbc oracle with tracking column, but don't work, need other information? like file.conf, etc.?

```
D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0>.\bin\logstash.bat -f D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0\config\conf.d\bo_firmas_electronicas.conf

Using LS_JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19
"WARNING: Logstash comes bundled with the recommended JDK(), but is overridden by the version defined in LS_JAVA_HOME. Consider clearing LS_JAVA_HOME to use the bundled JDK."
Sending Logstash logs to D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0\logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2023-01-13T15:00:09,087][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ArgumentError) Cannot determine timezone from nil\n(secs:1673640004.484,utc~:\"2023-01-13 20:00:04.48399996757507324\",ltz~:nil)\n(etz:nil,tnz:\"PET\",tziv:\"2.0.5\",tzidv:\"1.2022.6\",rv:\"2.6.8\",rp:\"java\",win:true,rorv:nil,astz:nil,eov:\"1.2.7\",eotnz:\"???\",eotnfz:\"???\",eotlzn:\"???\",\ndebian:nil,centos:nil,osx:nil)\nTry setting `ENV['TZ'] = 'Continent/City'` in your script (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:120)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt.initialize(AbstractPipelineExt.java:181)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$initialize.call(AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$initialize.gen)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:846)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1229)", "org.jruby.ir.instructions.InstanceSuperInstr.interpret(InstanceSuperInstr.java:131)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:361)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:128)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:115)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:911)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:549)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:361)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:92)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:238)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:225)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:226)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:393)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:206)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:325)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:116)", "org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:136)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:66)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:143)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:309)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:107)", "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)"]}
[2023-01-13T15:00:09,121][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:790) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:753) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at D_3a_.Elastic.logstash_minus_8_dot_6_dot_0.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:91) ~[?:?]

D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0>
D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0>.\bin\logstash.bat -f D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0\config\conf.d\bo_firmas_electronicas.conf
Using LS_JAVA_HOME defined java: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19
"WARNING: Logstash comes bundled with the recommended JDK(), but is overridden by the version defined in LS_JAVA_HOME. Consider clearing LS_JAVA_HOME to use the bundled JDK."
Sending Logstash logs to D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0\logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2023-01-13T15:02:00,714][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ArgumentError) Cannot determine timezone from nil\n(secs:1673640115.819,utc~:\"2023-01-13 20:01:55.8190000057220459\",ltz~:nil)\n(etz:nil,tnz:\"PET\",tziv:\"2.0.5\",tzidv:\"1.2022.6\",rv:\"2.6.8\",rp:\"java\",win:true,rorv:nil,astz:nil,eov:\"1.2.7\",eotnz:\"???\",eotnfz:\"???\",eotlzn:\"???\",\ndebian:nil,centos:nil,osx:nil)\nTry setting `ENV['TZ'] = 'Continent/City'` in your script (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:120)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt.initialize(AbstractPipelineExt.java:181)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$initialize.call(AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$initialize.gen)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:846)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1229)", "org.jruby.ir.instructions.InstanceSuperInstr.interpret(InstanceSuperInstr.java:131)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:361)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:128)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:115)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:911)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:329)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.ir.instructions.CallBase.interpret(CallBase.java:549)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:361)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:92)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:238)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:225)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:226)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:393)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:206)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:325)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.Interpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(Interpreter.java:116)", "org.jruby.runtime.MixedModeIRBlockBody.commonYieldPath(MixedModeIRBlockBody.java:136)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:66)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:143)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:309)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:107)", "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)"]}
[2023-01-13T15:02:00,748][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:790) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:753) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at D_3a_.Elastic.logstash_minus_8_dot_6_dot_0.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(D:\Elastic\logstash-8.6.0\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:91) ~[?:?]`
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data you are pushing to Logstash? I think this can be an issue related with timestamp.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs, your problem is related with timestamp issue :

```
Unable to configure plugins: (ArgumentError) Cannot determine timezone from nil\n(secs:1673640004.484,utc~:\"2023-01-13 20:00:04.48399996757507324\",ltz~:nil)\n(etz:nil,tnz:\"PET\",tziv:\"2.0.5\",tzidv:\"1.2022.6\",rv:\"2.6.8\",rp:\"java\",win:true,rorv:nil,astz:nil,eov:\"1.2.7\",eotnz:\"???\",eotnfz:\"???\",eotlzn:\"???\",\ndebian:nil,centos:nil,osx:nil)\nTry setting `ENV['TZ'] = 'Continent/City'` in your script (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
```

And, you can easily find similar questions are here:

- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/i-get-error-unable-to-configure-plugins-argumenterror-cannot-determine-timezone-from-nil/319531
- [Logstash 8.0 @timestamp with nanoseconds precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70783837/logstash-8-0-timestamp-with-nanoseconds-precision)
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nanoseconds-with-logstash-and-elasticsearch/282492

So, I think this answer you need to put inside the your pipeline too:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70804574/721600